# Passing a variable to shape selection

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a variable to select a certain shape and color it.
So I would like to use Sheet2.Shapes(varShapename).Select to select a shape (instead of using the actual name of the shape) and then change it's color. But it seems that I HAVE to use the actual name of the shape or use an index and I can't pass a variable.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub KeyCellsChanged()
   Dim Cell As Object
   ' If the values in B257:D277 are greater than 0
   For Each Cell In Range("B257:D277")
   If Cell < 0 Then
   ' Make the background color of the cell the 3rd color on the
   ' current palette.
   Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
   ' Select the first cell of the row, which holds the names of the shapes to change
   ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select
   Set shapeName = Selection
   Sheet2.Shapes(shapeName).Select
   Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
   Else
   ' Otherwise, set the background to none (default).
   Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

   End If
   Next Cell

End Sub
```

I get a runtime error 5.

Comment: What happens when you use the code you have? And what is the full code, including the part where you assign a value to the variable?

Comment: Please post any code which is potentially causing the problem and / or related to that code. Also, please let us know on which line of the code the problem occurs. FYI: it is possible to reference a shape using a string. So the problem must be within your code.

Comment: Added the code in the OP, ty for the quick replies for the sucky intro.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`Set shapeName = Selection`

use this instead

`shapeName = ActiveCell.Value`

Comment: Still get run time error 5: invalid procedure or argument :(

Comment: I don't get a line, it just says Run-Time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: Use F8 to step through your code...
Also make sure the shape name you have in the activecell actually refers to an existing shape on your active worksheet. You can use the following code to get a list of all shape names on the currently active worksheet:
`Sub getShapeNames()
    For Each Shape In Sheet1.Shapes
        Shapes = Shapes & Shape.Name & Chr(10)
    Next
    MsgBox Shapes
End Sub`

Comment: Hmm I think that's the problem, the shape is on a different sheet (in the same file ofc). I get a runtime error 438 now."object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: It stops at "Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)" and then gives the runtime error 438.

Comment: you will get error 438 if no shape on active worksheet is currently selected